# How to initiate Dell Command updates remotely with a Powershell script

Tags: powershell, intune

In short, I have an environment with ~165 devices requiring firmware updates available through Dell Command/Support Assist. I've tested a few scripts by changing to the Dell Command directory and then executing "dcu-cli.exe" with arguments to bypass prompts but haven't had much luck. Is there a way to initiate these updates on Dell Command (or Support Assist( 4.8.0 remotely with a Powershell script?

I'm utilizing Intune to push Powershell scripts within my environment and it should be noted I could manipulate a GPO to roll out DOS commands to essentially do that same thing, but Powershell is an easier method to access and work with.

Thank you,
Tim

Support Assist:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\DellInc.DellSupportAssistforPCs_3.13.7.0_x64__htrsf667h5kn2\Win32\SupportAssistAppWire.exe" -ArgumentList "/UpdateServiceStart", "/StartScan", "/Quiet" -Wait
```

Dell Command:

```
Set-Location -Path "C:\Program Files\Dell\"dell command location"
Start-Process "dcu-cli.exe" -ArgumentList "/applyUpdateServiceStart", "/Quiet" -Wait
```

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue with deployment with Dell command update. I use PDQ Deploy. After much online reading found that a bach file is easyer to work with.

my code looks like this

```
cd C:\Program Files\Dell\CommandUpdate

dcu-cli /version

dcu-cli /scan

dcu-cli /applyUpdates -encryptedPasswordFile="???" -encryptionKey="???"
```

Also not sure if you are trying to run the scan and the apply in the same code. I found that it is more stable to run them in diffrent steps.

hope this helps